# Using Tkinter, how can I get a button to appear when a radio choice is selected, and then disappear when that radio choice is no longer selected?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, hide

I've seen a fair few posts similar to the one I am making now, but I have not been able to utilise the advice / solution that has been provided. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

# Set up the window
app = Tk()
app.title("SUVAT Learning Game")
app.geometry("720x500+400+100")
menubar = Menu(app)

def highscorewindow():
    app = Tk()
    app.title("High Scores")
    app.geometry("720x500+400+100")

    # create an area for working
    large_field = Text(app)
    large_field.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 10)

    # create an area for an answer
    small_field = Entry(app)
    small_field.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 10)

#   create areas for the terms
#   term_entry1 = Entry(app)
#   term_entry1.visible = False
#   term_entry1.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 10)
#   term_entry1.pi = term_entry1.place_info()
#   term_entry1.place_forget()
#   term_entry2 = Entry(app)
#   term_entry2.visible = False
#   term_entry2.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 10)
#   term_entry2.pi = term_entry2.place_info()
#   term_entry2.place_forget()
#   term_entry3 = Entry(app)
#   term_entry3.visible = False
#   term_entry3.pack(side = 'bottom', pady = 10)
#   term_entry3.pi = term_entry3.place_info()
#   term_entry3.place_forget()


def callback():
    print(small_field.get())

def toggle():
    term_entry1.visible
    term_entry1.place(term_entry1.pi)       
    term_entry1.visible = not term_entry1.visible



# Set up the questions
questionnumber = random.randint(1, 5)

choice = IntVar()

if questionnumber == 1:
    Question = Label(app, text = "A ball is thrown in the air at 13 metres per second and reaches 15 metres into the air. \n\n Which equation is the correct one to use? \n\n Calculate the speed of the ball at this point.")
    Question.pack(side = 'top', pady = 32)

    # create answer 1 radio button
    Choice1 = Radiobutton(text = "V = (((2*S - U)) / t)", variable = choice, value = 1, command = "")
    Choice1.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 2 radio button
    Choice2 = Radiobutton(text = "t = (S / ((U + V) / 2))", variable = choice, value = 2, command = "")
    Choice2.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 3 radio button
    Choice3 = Radiobutton(text = "V = (math.sqrt((U*U) + 2*a*S))", variable = choice, value = 3, command = toggle) ####correct
    Choice3.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)


elif questionnumber == 2:
    Question = Label(app, text = "A truck is travelling at 25 metres per second when the brakes are applied. After 10 seconds, the truck comes to a stop. \n\n Which equation is the correct one to use? \n\n Calculate the deceleration of the truck.")
    Question.pack(side = 'top', pady = 32)

    # create answer 1 radio button
    Choice1 = Radiobutton(text = "a = ((V - U) / t)", variable = choice, value = 1, command = "") ####correct
    Choice1.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 2 radio button
    Choice2 = Radiobutton(text = "U = (S / (0.5*a*t))", variable = choice, value = 2, command = "")
    Choice2.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 3 radio button
    Choice3 = Radiobutton(text = "a = (S - (V*t) / (-0.5*(t*t)))", variable = choice, value = 3, command = "")
    Choice3.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)


elif questionnumber == 3:
    Question = Label(app, text = "A tennis ball is thrown in the air. After 20 seconds, the ball reaches its maximum height. \n\n Which equation is the correct one to use? \n\n Calculate the initial speed of the ball.")
    Question.pack(side = 'top', pady = 32)

    # create answer 1 radio button
    Choice1 = Radiobutton(text = "U = (V / a*t)", variable = choice, value = 1, command = "") ####correct
    Choice1.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 2 radio button
    Choice2 = Radiobutton(text = "U = (S / (0.5*a*t))", variable = choice, value = 2, command = "")
    Choice2.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 3 radio button
    Choice3 = Radiobutton(text = "S = (V*t - 0.5*a*(t*t))", variable = choice, value = 3, command = "")
    Choice3.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)


elif questionnumber == 4:
    Question = Label(app, text = "A firework travels upwards after being launched with a speed of 20 metres per second. \n\n Which equation is the correct one to use? \n\n Calculate the greatest height reached by the firework.")
    Question.pack(side = 'top', pady = 32)

    # create answer 1 radio button
    Choice1 = Radiobutton(text = "S = (((V*V)-(U*U) / 2*a))", variable = choice, value = 1, command = "") ####correct
    Choice1.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 2 radio button
    Choice2 = Radiobutton(text = "S = ((U*t) + 0.5*a*(t*t))", variable = choice, value = 2, command = "")
    Choice2.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 3 radio button
    Choice3 = Radiobutton(text = "a = (S / (U*t*0.5*(t*t)))", variable = choice, value = 3, command = "")
    Choice3.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)


elif questionnumber == 5:
    Question = Label(app, text = "A well is 75 metres deep. A pebble is dropped from the top, and hits the bottom with a speed of 12 metres per second. \n\n Which equation is the correct one to use? \n\n Calculate the time the pebble takes to travel from top to bottom.")
    Question.pack(side = 'top', pady = 32)

    # create answer 1 radio button
    Choice1 = Radiobutton(text = "t = (S / ((U + V) / 2))", variable = choice, value = 1, command = "")
    Choice1.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 2 radio button
    Choice2 = Radiobutton(text = "S = ((U*t) + 0.5*a*(t*t))", variable = choice, value = 2, command = "")
    Choice2.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

    # create answer 3 radio button
    Choice3 = Radiobutton(text = "t = ((V - U) / a)", variable = choice, value = 3, command = "") ####correct
    Choice3.pack(side = 'top', padx = 10)

# create a pulldown menu for scores, and add it to the menu bar
scoremenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
scoremenu.add_command(label="View Highscores", command=highscorewindow)
scoremenu.add_command(label="Clear Highscores", command=callback)
scoremenu.add_command(label="New Question", command="")
scoremenu.add_separator()
scoremenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=app.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Score Menu", menu=scoremenu)

# create pulldown menu for help
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About", command="")
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)

nextbutton = Button(text = "Next", command = highscorewindow)
nextbutton.pack(side = 'top', pady = 10)
nextbutton.position_forget()

# display the menu
app.config(menu=menubar)

mainloop()
```

As you can see from my code, I'm very average at coding with Python. My code could probably be a whole lot more efficient, I realise, but I just don't have the know-how to make that happen, which is why I come here for help. If any of you fancy helping out, I'm happy to explain my code more.

Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: Are you trying to write a program designed to quiz people on various questions?

Comment: Yes, but implementing the rest of the questioning parts of the program comes a little bit later.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/sets/33-quiz-me-25/ and modifying the souce code there. You can also get an archived, working version of the code by emailing the developer at Stephen.P.Chappell@gmail.com

Comment: See, that does look good but alas, this is for a coursework piece so I can't really take up such a huge chunk of code. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
button.pack_forget()
button.pack()
```

or

```
button.grid_forget()
button.grid()
```

or

```
button.place_forget()
button.place()
```

the checkbutton seems to have `Radiobutton(master, command = function)`

you can use the above methods of the button mentioned above in the function.

Comment: You might want to mention that `grid_remove` can also be used, and it has the advantage that it remembers where the item was, so a simple call to `grid()` puts it right back. With the `_forget` methods, you have to make sure to include all the appropriate options for putting it back where it was (which, for pack, often means you need to include a `before` or `after` attribute since the order that things are packed is significant.

Comment: Is there any chance that you could write a little bit of code, using the piece that I've put above, with the implementation of the grid_remove method? As I can't seem to get it to work alongside the radio buttons still.